# Is it possible to use exec() to instantiate a class in python?

Tags: python, exec, eval

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, nex = None):
        self.value = value
        self.nex = nex

class List(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(6)

    def ins(self, val):
        exec('b = Node(val)')
        self.head.nex = b
```

My purpose is to set any string as a variable name.

Comment: I don't see any reason for it not to be possible. The exec statement is executed in the current scope. using `b=exec('Node(val)')` should work just fine, but this example does not show any added value to using `exec`. Can you demonstrate what is the purpose of using it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently it is, because your code works (although I don't think it's doing what you intend it to do, you probably wanna change List.head during List.ins() or something).

```
>>> class List(Node):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.head = Node(6)
...     def ins(self, val):
...         exec('b = Node(val)')
...         self.head.nex = b
...
>>> x = List()
>>> x.ins('a')
>>> x.head.value
6
>>> x.head.nex.value
'a'
```

As for setting "any string" as a variable name, that works too

```
>>> exec ("%s = %s" % (raw_input(),raw_input()))
a
'b'
>>> a
'b'
```

But you seriously, really, absolutely shouldn't ever do that ever (you should almost never use exec at all). It would literally open your program up to being totally hijacked. If you're trying to load a config file or something, consider using these strings as dictionary keys instead of variable names. "Sandbox" the input.

Comment: first time using stack overflow, not sure if u can see my answer with '@yourname', so leave a comment here so u can see it.

Comment: I can't comment on your answer yet (newbie SO reputation), so regarding your answer: yes, you can use setattr. Still, I wouldn't do that, especially not with anything like user input. Too much opportunity for exploits or odd breakages.

Answer (score 0):

@Benny Mackney
i find another way to do this by using setattr:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value = None, nex = None):
        self.val = value
        self.nex = nex

class List(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()

    def ins(self):
        li = []
        for i in range(10):
            setattr(self,'n' + str(i), Node(i))


        #self.n0.nex = self.n1
        #self.n1.nex = self.n2
        #self.n2.nex = self.n3
        #.
        #.
        #.
        #self.n8.nex = self.n9
```

so now i have 9 nodes from self.n0 to self.n9
how do i connect them so i can get:
self.head.nex = self.n0
self.n0.nex = self.n1
etc...